# How can I get the file size from a link without downloading it in python?

Tags: python, get

I have a list of links that I am trying to get the size of to determine how much computational resources each file need. Is it possible to just get the file size with a get request or something similar?

Here is an example of one of the links: https://sra-download.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/traces/sra46/SRR/005150/SRR5273887

Thanks

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909/get-size-of-a-file-before-downloading-in-python).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To do this use the HTTP HEAD method which just grabs the header information for the URL and doesn't download the content like an HTTP GET request does.

```
$curl -I https://sra-download.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/traces/sra46/SRR/005150/SRR5273887
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 18 Mar 2019 16:56:35 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 578220087
Last-Modified: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 12:13:19 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

The file size is in the 'Content-Length' header. In Python 3.6:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> req = urllib.request.Request('https://sra-download.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/traces/sra46/SRR/005150/SRR5273887', 
                                 method='HEAD')
>>> f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
>>> f.status
200
>>> f.headers['Content-Length']
'578220087'
```

Comment: note if the remote server does not implement head you can still achieve something similar by using the stream = True option with the python requests library as on https://stackoverflow.com/a/44299915  and then closing each request directly after you have obtained their headers.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the `HEAD` method. The example uses [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org) (`pip install requests`).

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# display URL file size without downloading

import sys
import requests

# pass URL as first argument
response = requests.head(sys.argv[1], allow_redirects=True)

size = response.headers.get('content-length', -1)

# size in megabytes (Python 2, 3)
print('{:<40}: {:.2f} MB'.format('FILE SIZE', int(size) / float(1 << 20)))

# size in megabytes (f-string, Python 3 only)
# print(f"{'FILE SIZE':<40}: {int(size) / float(1 << 20):.2f} MB")
```

Also see [How do you send a HEAD HTTP request in Python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python-2) if you need a standard-library based solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3, you can do it using [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) from [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.request.html):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
link =  "https://sra-download.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/traces/sra46/SRR/005150/SRR5273887"
site = urlopen(link)
meta = site.info()
print(meta)
```

This will output:

```
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 18 Mar 2019 17:02:40 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 578220087
Last-Modified: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 12:13:19 GMT
Connection: close
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

The `Content-Length` property is the size of your file in bytes.

Comment: `urlopen` will do a `GET` request and will in fact download the document.