# How can I get size of file while downloading it in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

How can I get size of file while downloading it in Python so that I can show downloaded size and pending size of file to download? if file size is 2GB and 700mb is downloaded then how will we get that in python. Currently using Python requests module to download file.

example code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(download_link)
with open('setup.exe','wb') as file:
    file.write()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get file size using python-requests, while only getting the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270698/get-file-size-using-python-requests-while-only-getting-the-header)

Comment: @DYZ it is just giving total file size.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the file size from the header

```
import requests
r = requests.get(download_link)
headers = r.headers
file_size = headers.get('Content-Length')
```

Comment: it will just give me total file size not downloaded or pending file size.

Answer (score 1):

I too was looking for a solution and found one. Use `requests` with `stream=True` and `tqdm`.

To install tqdm with python3, use:

```
python3 -m pip install tqdm
```

Code to download a video from [MITOpenCourseWare](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/resources/lecture-1-algorithmic-thinking-peak-finding/):

```
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm

link = 'http://www.archive.org/download/MIT6.006F11/MIT6_006F11_lec01_300k.mp4'
filename = 'video.mp4'
response = requests.get(link, stream=True)
if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    total_size = int(response.headers.get('Content-Length', 0))
    downloaded_size = 0
    print(f'contentLength: {total_size} MB')
    with open(filename, 'wb') as handle,\
        tqdm(unit='B', total=total_size, desc=filename, unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024) as bar:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024*1024):
            size = handle.write(chunk)
            bar.update(size)
            downloaded_size += size
```

The variable `downloaded_size` for each loop gives the current downloaded size and `total_size` gives the total size.

Assumptions:

1. The website responds with a `Content-Length`

Answer (score 0):

I found what i was looking for:
ref: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow

```
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
   downloaded=0
   total =  int(r.headers['content-length'])
   for i in r.iter_content():
       downloaded+=len(i)
       print(downloaded)
```