# Using tqdm or similiar to update a wx.Gauge on a wxPython application

Tags: python, download, wxpython, tqdm

I'm trying to build an app that downloads a file and updates a wx.Gauge in real time with the download progress. Additionally, I would like to show the current downloaded size / total size and a real time updating download speed.

In my minimal code example, the progress variable, which would have a value between 0 and 100, is set to **perc_value**. The size and current speed text is set to **progress_text**.

I tried using tqdm, but their examples shows their own implementation of progress bar and speed. I couldn't find a variable/function from their library to give me those info.

Can you help me?
Thank you!

```
import wx
import requests
from threading import Thread

class DownloadThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, parent, url):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.url = url
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        perc_value = 0
        progress_text = ''
        with open('file', 'wb') as f:
            r = requests.get(self.url, stream=True)
            for chunk in r.iter_content(4096):
                f.write(chunk)
                wx.CallAfter(self.parent.update_gauge, perc_value, progress_text)

class Main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self, -1)
        self.progress_t = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Testing")

        sizer.Add(self.gauge, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        sizer.Add(self.progress_t, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.start_download()

    def start_download(self):
        url = '.../file.zip'
        DownloadThread(self, url)

    def update_gauge(self, perc_value, progress_text):
        self.gauge.SetValue(perc_value)
        self.progress_t.SetLabel(progress_text)

app = wx.App()
Main(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

***Edit:***
I have made some improvements. I found the best solution is not using tqdm. My only problem now is the download speed, which is inaccurate.

***Edit2: Solved the problem. The corrected version is below!***

```
import wx
import requests
from threading import Thread

class DownloadThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, parent, url):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.url = url
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        perc_temp = 0
        r = requests.get(self.url, stream=True)
        self.total_length = r.headers.get('content-length')

        with open('file.data', 'wb') as f:
            if self.total_length is None: # no content length header
                f.write(r.content)
            else:
                self.dl = 0
                self.dl_temp = 0
                self.total_length = int(self.total_length)
                
                self.total_size = self.get_downloaded_value(self.total_length)
                self.total_unit = self.get_unit(self.total_length)

                print(self.total_length)
                for data in r.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
                    self.dl += len(data)
                    self.dl_temp += len(data)
                    f.write(data)
                    value = int(100 * self.dl / self.total_length)
                    if perc_temp != value:
                        perc_temp = value
                        wx.CallAfter(self.parent.update_gauge, value)

    def get_progress_text(self):
        downloaded = self.get_downloaded_value(self.dl)
        unit_downloaded = self.get_unit(self.dl)

        speed = self.get_downloaded_value(self.dl_temp)
        speed_unit = self.get_unit(self.dl_temp)

        text = f"{downloaded:.2f} {unit_downloaded} / {self.total_size:.2f} {self.total_unit}\t\t{speed:.2f} {speed_unit}/s"

        self.dl_temp = 0
        return text

    def get_unit(self, size):
        unit = ''
        if size < 1024:
            unit = 'B'
        elif size < 1048576:
            unit = 'KB'
        else:
            unit = 'MB'

        return unit

    def get_downloaded_value(self, size):
        if size < 1024:
            return size
        elif size < 104876:
            return size / 1024
        else:
            return size / 1048576


class Main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer)

        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self, -1)
        self.progress_t = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Testing", size=(300, 23))

        sizer.Add(self.gauge, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, border=10)
        sizer.Add(self.progress_t, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, border=10)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.start_download()

    def start_download(self):
        url = 'https://portal.inmet.gov.br/uploads/dadoshistoricos/2008.zip'
        self.thread = DownloadThread(self, url)
        self.timer.Start(1000)

    def update_gauge(self, perc_value):
        self.gauge.SetValue(perc_value)

    def OnTimer(self, event):
        self.progress_t.SetLabel(self.thread.get_progress_text())
        

app = wx.App()
Main(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: See the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62508831/how-can-i-get-size-of-file-while-downloading-it-in-python

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Unfortunately, that didn't helped me. It shows the conventional way of using tqdm.

Comment: I'm just happy that something pushed you in the direction of `r.headers.get('content-length')`